# event.target.innerText not retaining the new line - Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `conteneditable div` where I am showing some pre-populated grey text with attribute `data-suggestion`.

When the text is clicked:

1. I am changing it to black color
2. removing the attribute `data-suggestion` from selected line.

The input event on `contenteditable div` will call the function `onInput()` and then I will get the text in a `final_doc_summary` variable.

**Problem**:

1. The new line is not preserved in the `final_doc_summary` variable when event is fired.
2. I want to filter only those text which do not have `data-suggestion` attribute in the `final_doc_summary` variable.

---

```
<div
    id="div_textarea2"
    class="textarea mb-3"
    contenteditable="true"
    v-html="doc_summary"
    @input="event=>onInput(event,index)"
></div>


data(){
     return {
           final_doc_summary:'',
           suggestion_list : ['Line 1','Line 2','Line 3'],
     }
}

    mounted(){
      this.AddSuggestedLine();    

}

methods: {
    onInput(event, index){
      this.final_doc_summary  = $(event.target).text();
      
    },

    AddSuggestion1() {
      for (var i=0;i<this.suggestion_list.length; i++){
        var suggestions  = "<div><span data-suggestion=true class='suggestedContent' id='suggested-content-"+i+"'>" +this.suggestion_list[i]+ "</span></div>";
        this.doc_summary +=suggestions;
      }
    },
}
```

Below JQuery code make the text black and removes the attribute `data-suggestion`:

```
  $(".suggestedContent").click(function () {
    $(this).css({ color: "black", "text-decoration": "none" });
    $(this).removeAttr('data-suggestion');
  });
```

Comment: Where is `event.target.innerText` used in your code? Notice also, that "new-lines" created by text wrapping are not real, they don't appear in any values you can retrieve from the content editable.

Comment: See onInput() function... I tried jquery $(event.target).text() and vanilaJS  event.target.innerText

Comment: In that function I see `.text()`, it's not equivalent to native `innerText`. It's also notable, that a content editable element doesn't create a textual new-line (i.e. `\n`) when you hit ENTER, it creates an element like `<br>`, `<div>` or `<p>`.

Comment: but I tried both as I said earlier, both gives me a single line result... although my suggested lines are like <div><span>Line 1</span></div> and while inspecting it shows me a <br> between these divs

Comment: Yes, that's an element, innerText et.al. retrieves the text content only, not elements. If you need elements, chek innerHTML.

Comment: How can I get the tags and filter those tags which do not have data-suggestion attribute, I need only those text which dont have this attribute.

Comment: Create a [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range), find the parent element and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) with an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Answer (score 1):

Try using **event.target.textContent** instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

> Don't get confused by the differences between Node.textContent and
> HTMLElement.innerText. Although the names seem similar, there are
> important differences:

> textContent gets the content of all elements, including  and  elements. In contrast, innerText only shows
> "human-readable" elements.

> textContent returns every element in the node. In contrast, innerText is aware of styling and won't return the text of "hidden"
> elements.

You might also need to add some JS to insert a newline (\n) when the user press enter. The browser normally adds a br on enter. And set the css style white-space: pre-line for newlines to be rendered properly.

```
<div
id="div_textarea2"
style="white-space: pre-line"
class="textarea mb-3"
contenteditable="true"
v-html="doc_summary"
@keydown.enter.prevent="addNewLine"
@input="event=>onInput(event,index)"
```

> 

```
methods: {
  addNewLine (event) {
    const selection = window.getSelection()
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0)

    // create a new text node with a newline character
    const newline = document.createTextNode('\n')

    // insert the newline at the current caret position
    range.insertNode(newline)

    // move the caret to the end of the newline
    range.setStartAfter(newline)
    range.setEndAfter(newline)
    selection.removeAllRanges()
    selection.addRange(range)
  }
}
```